# Rollback UUID type in a Laravel migration

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, uuid, migrate

I'm switching to UUID primary keys using Ramsey\Uuid package and it works great. The only issue encountered so far is when I run php artisan migrate:rollback to change it back to original primary key id:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or
>   access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for th e right
>   syntax to use near 'CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NOT NULL COLLATE
>   `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`' at line 1 (SQL: ALTER TABLE model_has_roles
>   CHANGE model_id model_id BIGINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT CHARACTER SET
>   utf 8mb4 NOT NULL COLLATE `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`)

My code:

```
public function up()
{
    if(!Type::hasType('uuid')) {
        Type::addType('uuid', 'Ramsey\Uuid\Doctrine\UuidType');
    }

    Schema::table('model_has_roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->uuid('model_id')->change();
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::table('model_has_roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('model_id')->change();
    });

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be up against this issue:https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/issues/3714

The consensus is that adding `->charset(null)` to your column definition is the best way to get around the problem in the short term.

Try

```
public function down()
{
    Schema::table('model_has_roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('model_id')->charset(null)->change();
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I now get the following error:  Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'eccabb09-03de-4d9f-bbb3-4f876f7339ae
                                              ' (SQL: ALTER TABLE model_has_roles CHANGE model_id model_id BIGINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL COLLATE `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`)